# How to acknowledge a retired professor?

Tags: acknowledgement

I want to acknowledge a retired professor. How do I specify his name? With just Prof. or something particular?

Comment: This will probably depend on your field, and even the specific journal/venue, some of which may have already been addressed in other Q&A's.  We'll need those details.

Answer (score 8):

I usually see acknowledgements in papers with just the full name of the person, regardless of their degrees or academic status.  No "Prof." or other honorific would be used at all.  "We would like to thank Jane Doe for helpful advice regarding our data analysis."

Comment: What about when I refer to them in the text: `according to private discussion with Prof. (ret.), the domain was earlier called ...`? So then I use the titles but no titles in the acknowledgements?

Comment: @hhh If you must, write Dr. Doe, but it would seem weird to me. In an international journal, I'd write "according to private discussion with Jane Doe, ...". Of course, it would be totally different issue when writing for a national journal because then local customs have to be considered.

Answer (score 1):

Where a person who previously held rank or position has now left through retiring from the position (as opposed to resignation or termination), it is not uncommon to see them listed as **Rank (ret.) Person Name**.

For a professor, this would be **Prof. (ret.) Person Name**.

Comment: In academia titles, latin is usually preferred. On the faculty list you often see Prof. (emer.) which is used for Professors in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emeritus status.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse But of course emeritus and retired are two different things.

Answer (score 1):

In USA, a retired professor is not probably called a professor. A retired professor with doctorate can continued to be called as Dr. and identified in bio or intorduction as a former professor.